# Youtube stream fmt_stream_map error with regional restriction

Tags: php, video, download, youtube, stream

Have php script that generates stream urls from youtube video id.
Here is link I am using:

http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?el=detailpage&asv=3&video_id=**{video_id}**

I get `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map`from this link and decode it to get urls. If video is using cipher signature then I decode it and generate working urls.
It works for all cases except regional restriction. My server is located in US and can't get video stream blocked in US.

For example: 
This video **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrCI35uAqiw** is blocked in US so I am getting this error from `get_video_info` :

> reason=This+video+contains+content+from+Wediacorp%2C+who+has+blocked+it+in+your+country+on+copyright+grounds.&errordetail=0&errorcode=150&status=fail

If you have any solutions please share.

Thanks,
Shota.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer :**

> You really should only use this method for accessing **your own**
>   video file content (like if Youtube holds a backup copy). If you just
>   take any multiple videos, you risk closing this option for all of us.

Morality rant over...

Instead of: http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?el=detailpage&asv=3&video_id=video_id

Try this instead: http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=DrCI35uAqiw